# Clicking a ListView that has a longclick item on it

Tags: android, listview, onclick, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I have studied a number of answers to similar questions but none work in this particular instance (which isn't covered anywhere else).

- I have a `ListView` containing `ListItems` with a number of `TextView`s on each.
- When I do a **short click** on any `ListItem` I am expanding that item to show more information (by implementing an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`).
- One of the `TextView`s has `android:longClickable="true"` set. This is so that I can run another action when that particular `TextView` is **long clicked** (I achieved this by implementing `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener` and checking for the particular `TextView` id)
- I have set `android:clickable="false"` for that `TextView`

My issue is that now when I do a **short click** anywhere on the `ListItem` the item expands as expected - EXCEPT when the **short click** is on that particular `TextView`, in which case nothing happens.

So the **short click** is being consumed by something even though I have set clickable to false?

Have I missed something obvious? If I set the `android:longClickable="false"` on that `TextView` then the expansion works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the event is interrupted by the long click listener.

Try to check the return value of the "onItemLongClickListener", it's a boolean type, which will decide the event is handled or not.

Good luck!

Comment: I think you've missed my point. I'm not doing a long click so the `onItemLongClickListener` isn't fired. What I want to happen is for the `onClickListener` for the `ListItem` which contains the `TextItem` to be fired. But what actually happens is...nothing.